# "It turns out" vs. "It turned out"

Tags: tense

One of my friends asked me about another friend Jim yesterday, I said

> Jim thought he could get a promotion this year, Jim did his best to get the promotion. **It turned out** he didn't make it, as his colleague, Michael, did better and got the promotion.

Should I have said this?

> ... **It turns out** ...

Which one is more clear and natural?

Are there any other expressions more natural could be used for the situation?

Answer (score 1):

As the outcome of Jim's attempt was in the past (you say *Michael got the promotion* as though that is now an established fact), it's fine to use *turned out.*

You would say *it turns out* if you had only recently learned of the outcome. "Mary has just had her exam results - it turns out she passed in all subjects."

Comment: Thank you. The outcome/result was published/released last week while the competition between Jim and Michael had lasted half a year. Which one should I use?

Comment: Whichever you want. If you are still thinking of it as a recent development, of course you can use the present tense.